# Remove framework from project explorer Xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks

Can someone please tell me how to remove a frame work from project explorer in Xcode, trying to delete it gives the error message "......” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it. To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

Deleting it from this source removes it from the Lib file on the hard drive I just want to remove it from the project. Your advice please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you remove it, do you select *Remove Reference Only* or *Delete*?  Most frameworks you add to an Xcode project are system frameworks; you shouldn't be attempting to delete these from disk as they form part of the SDK.  You should just select *Remove Reference Only*.

If you are doing this and still getting the error, then it's probably because you don't have permission to modify the project files themselves.  Check the permissions on the `.xcodeproj` bundle.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jim, I used Remove Reference Only worked fine no crashes

Comment: If we found those frameworks  deleted,when we try to do link binary with libraries  what should we do?